# Svelte: add noscroll class name to body from component

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte

I have a `src/components/UI/Sidebar.svelte` component with a variable toggle.

```js
export let toggle = true;
```

I would like to add a class name of `noscroll` to the `<body>` when toggle is true to lock the body scroll. I have added this on the `src/template.html`

```html
<style>
    .noscroll { position: fixed; overflow-y:scroll };
</style>
```

What would it be the best way to implement a y-axis scroll lock like this when the sidebar is open?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your Sidebar.svelte you add a reactive function that toggles the classname

```js
export let toggle;
$: document.body.classList[toggle ? 'add' : 'remove']('noscroll');
```

**updated**

Thanks to Rich Harris to point out that toggle takes a second argument [specs](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-domtokenlist) this can be simplified to

```js
export let toggle;

$: if (process.browser) document.body.classList.toggle('noscroll', toggle);
```

**edit**
When using SvelteKit which came into public beta since this question was asked, you can also use the `browser` variable provided.

```js
export let toggle;
import { browser } from '$app/env'

$: if (browser) document.body.classList.toggle('noscroll', toggle);
```

Comment: @StephaneVanreas thanks fo that info and this is what I thought I needed to do. But when I add this in the components script I get an error `ReferenceError: document is not defined`. Does it matter that I am also using Sapper?

Comment: It does matter, yes — that statement will fail in the server-side rendering phase. Also, you can do `classList.toggle(name, condition)` which is more compact — so you could change the whole statement to `$: if (process.browser) document.body.classList.toggle('noscroll', toggle)`

Comment: Woah! Thanks @RichHarris this did the trick!!! Thanks for the insight and I really enjoy working with Svelte.